# Using translucent UINavigationBars

Tags: iphone

I am using InterfaceBuilder to set up my app. I have several views being controlled by a UINavigationController. In IB I set up the views using the simulated metrics to position the elements below the Navigation Bar.

I have a background texture that is placed in the window object of the Main.nib so that it is shared throughout the app. I want that texture to be visible behind a transucent navigation bar.

If the actual navigationBar's style is BlackOpaque the elements of the various views are positioned correctly below the navBar when the app is run.

If I set the NavigationBar to be translucent, view elements are repositioned to the bottom of the status bar when the app is run so that they are visible behind the navigationBar, even though they are positioned correctly in their various nib files.

How do I defeat this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the answer...

If you do NOT want objects to be slid up to be positioned behind a translucent NavigationBar, In IB, set the simulated metrics for the navBar to none, and position the view elements as desired.